# How to find specific element in a String[]?

Tags: java

So i have a String[] (equipment) with 5 different string elements in it, i want to search the array for a specific element and I am unsure how to achieve this.

```
public class Car {

    private int number;
    private int id;
    private String headline;
    double price;
    private int year;
    String [] equipment;
    ...
    this.equipment = new String[5];
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(this.equipment).indexOf(search);` edit: assuming I'm understanding what you're asking.

Comment: I'm probably not asking a question right way(sorry new in this)...let's say i have these 5 attributes in String - ABS, ESP, Alarm, Airbag,DVD - I want let's say to put in "CD" so that the program goes through the string and determine whether I have that attribute or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to find the index of a certain String.

```
String toFind = "";
int index = -1;

// for loop
for(int i = 0; i < equipment.length; i++) {
    if(equipment[i].equals(toFind) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

// list conversion (inefficient but concise)
index = Arrays.asList(equipment).indexOf(toFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end you'll wind up with linear search (probably provided by some API-method), so here we go with a few ways:

### The school-book linear search

The basic idea is to run through the array, until we encounter the string that is searched. Or run to the end of the array and return -1, which represents "element doesn't exist" by convention.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
    if(array[i].equals(searched)){ //no check for null-values for simplicity!!!!
        return i;
    }
}

return -1;
```

### java.util.Arrays#asList + indexOf

You can as well [create a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Arrays.html) of all items, and leave the linear search to the list-implementation. The algorithm behind the scenes will still be a linear search though.

```
return java.util.Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(searched);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it :)